# Collections - Filtering multiple multi-select attribute values

Tags: attributes, collection, mysql

That's not a typo.

I am aware that I need to use 'finset' to filter my multi-select attributes; however, I am trying to filter multiple values at once and getting:

`Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET`.

Here's some sample code:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
    // $option[0] contains an attribute ID as a string
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($option[0]);

    if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), array('finset' => $option[1]));
    } else {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), array('in' => $option[1]));
    }
}
```

What I have on the frontend is a set of fields, each set corresponds to a specific attribute and contains checkboxes for each attribute value. Based on these submissions, the collection should filter out what has been selected.

Everything works great except for the single case where I attempt to filter two of the multi-select options at the same time. If I only choose one of them, the search works properly. If I choose two or more, I get the MySQL error mentioned above.

Any ideas? Or am I forced to use custom SQL statements to build this filter?

Comment: If you are trying to filter multiple select input type try filtering using `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` table.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From what I understand you want to send 2 or more values and filter by them using `OR`.
Something like this:

```
...
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET($v1, `some_field`) OR
    FIND_IN_SET($v2, `some_field`) OR
...
```

`$v1 & $v2` are the values of your checkboxes

For that you need to pass to the `addAttributeToFilter` and array of arrays.

```
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
          array('attribute'=>'some_attribute', 'finset'=>$v1),
          array('attribute'=>'some_attribute', 'finset'=>$v2),
    )
);
```

Here is a possible implementation.

```
$data = THE ARRAY OF THE CHECKBOX VALUES;

$filter = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $filter[] = array(
        'attribute' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
        'finset'    => $value
    );
}

if (count($filter) > 0) {
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
}
```

Comment: I am getting my category id like this($exist_prdcat_id = 4,5 so i use ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
    array('finset' => array($exist_prdcat_id)),
  ));  but i am not getting product why?? can you tell me this

Comment: I want to filter start_date and end_date, How do you do?

Comment: where should I place this code??

Comment: @ktsixit Where you need it.

Comment: How can i perform 'and'.  I mean want to filter product collection based on multiple multi-select attribute values. @Marius can you help?

Comment: Hello,
I want to show all products section wise, like first option and its products, then 2nd option than its products and so on. So, I have used it within loop function in list.phtml : Like foreach ($optionIds as $optionid):
        $optionid = (int) $optionid; $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->clear()->addAttributeToFilter(
                        array(
                            array('attribute' => "filter_type", 'finset' =>$optionid)
                        )
                    );But its only showing one time with first options products only.

Answer (score -1):

This code will combine two `finset` conditions with `OR`:

```
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
          array('attribute'=>'some_attribute', 'finset'=>$v1),
          array('attribute'=>'some_attribute', 'finset'=>$v2),
    )
);
```