# Collection with FIND_IN_SET on multiselect attributes, but some has only one value

Tags: product-collection, multiselect-attribute

I am building a product collection, which will find results from a multiselect attribute.

(relevant code that adds finset to collection - adjusted to display real id values)

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'measurement');
    $value = array('finset' => array('237',
                '236',
                '235',
                '234',
                '233',));
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value);
```

The resulting sql (with visiblity filter added) is as such:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e . *,
    at_measurement.value AS measurement,
    at_visibility.value AS visibility
FROM
    catalog_product_entity AS e
        INNER JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS at_measurement ON (at_measurement.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_measurement.attribute_id = '983') AND (at_measurement.store_id = 0)
        INNER JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int AS at_visibility ON (at_visibility.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_visibility.attribute_id = '526') AND (at_visibility.store_id = 0)
WHERE
    (e.attribute_set_id IN ('74')) AND (FIND_IN_SET('237',
            '236',
            '235',
            '234',
            '233',
            at_measurement.value)) AND (at_visibility.value IN ('2' , '4'))
GROUP BY e.entity_id
```

The issue is that I get a sql error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET'"
```

and I (think) I can see why: Some of the multiselect values have only one option, thus there is no comma separated values to qualify for FINSET

Am I correct in why this error is produced?
How can I write this collection object to account for this?

If not the above, what am I missing?

The results from running the sql in mysql workbench, minus the find_in_set clause:

[image: results checked in query editor]

Comment: duplicate of: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14109/collections-filtering-multiple-multi-select-attribute-values

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to use addAttributeToFilter with or condition

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute,
    array(
        array('finset'=> array('237')),
        array('finset'=> array('238')),
        array('finset'=> array('239')),
    )
);
```

Or

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'attributecode','finset' => array('237')),
        array('attribute'=> 'attributecode','finset' => array('237')),
        array('attribute'=> 'attributecode','finset' => array('237')),
    )
);
```

Comment: How can we do NOT FIND_IN_SET ?

Comment: How to use 'AND' condition

Comment: For "AND", just repeat the $collection->addAttributeToFilter() for each value