# Magento 2 - How to use mysql find_in_set?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, sql, query

In Magento 2, I try to use find_in_set mysql function but without success.

I try this :

```
$result->getSelect()->order("find_in_set(e.entity_id,'".implode(',',$sort_order)."')");
```

But it give me an error :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'find_in_set(e.entity_id,'730,740,753,....
```

I also try this but it doesn't work :

```
$result->addFieldToFilter('e.entity_id',array("finset"=>$sort_order));
```

Do you have an idea about the problem ? And how to make it work ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I find a solution, with Zend_Db_Expr, this line work for considering "find_in_set(..." as a function and not a column name :

```
$result->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("find_in_set(e.entity_id,'".implode(',',$sort_order)."')"));
```

Comment: you are check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14593/85907 ???

Comment: @MohitPatel Thanks, but I can't get it to work..

Comment: i think problem is Column. Please confirm database columns name ...

Comment: Yes because it consider "find_in_set" as column and not function, but I don't know how to change this interpretation.

Comment: @MohitPatel see my edit I find a solution

Comment: Sounds good, Solve your issue???