# getting error after change attribute input type

Tags: attributes, ce-1.8.1.0, products

I have a page that I getting all products with some attributes. (room, color, size, price)

I change "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" for room attribute on database. It was dropdown, now multiselect.

After this change the page returning null. Is anyone know why?

It's the part of code:

```
$room = $_POST['room'];
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    //->addAttributeToFilter('color', 7)
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $catID))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('in'=>$size))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('room', array('in'=>$room))
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
    ->setPage($pageNumber, $productPerPage)
    ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
    //$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
    //$collection->getSelect()->limit(12);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt'=>$priceL));
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lt'=>$priceG));
```

Edit: If I remove "`->addAttributeToFilter('room', array('in'=>$room))`" line, it's perfectly working.

Comment: are you using a flat catalog?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `$room` is one of the values from the available options of the `room` attribute.
Since the multiselects are saved in the db as a string with values concatenated by comma `(1,4,5,6,7,15)`, you need to filter like this:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('room', array('finset'=>$room));
```

If the `$room` variable is an array you need to apply a multiple `FIND_IN_SET` filter with `or` condition.
See an example for [this kind of filter in here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14116/146)

Comment: returned this error: http://pastebin.com/jk6Frg6L

Comment: @ibrahim What is the value of the `$room` variable?

Comment: $room = array("3","4","5","6");

Comment: @ibrahim. In this case you need a different kind of filter. See my updated answer.

Comment: @ibrahim. Did it work?

Comment: I'm trying but I also tried this: ->addAttributeToFilter('room', array('finset'=>"3")) But it also doesn't work. Is it normal?

Comment: that's not normal, It should work.

Comment: I also tried your example in that page but returned null again. Here is my full of code: http://pastebin.com/54cJqHJ3 If I remove anything about room attributes it works.

Comment: I also deleted attribute and add again with same options. Then change their values on code but still return null.