# Sort collection on labels of multi-select attribute values

Tags: collection, filter, sorting

I found [this sollution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14116/29653) for filtering multiple multi-select attribute values.

```
$data = THE ARRAY OF THE CHECKBOX VALUES;

$filter = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $filter[] = array(
        'attribute' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
        'finset'    => $value
    );
}

if (count($filter) > 0) {
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
}
```

I need to filter the output alphabetically. For example my attribute looks like this:

```
Label     Value
apple     1051
banana    1052
pear      1053
melon     1054
```

and I want to sort it not on values but on labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by sorting on **sort_order**

```
if (count($filter) > 0) {
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
    $collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);

    $dir = Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC;
    $dir = strtoupper($dir);

    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft('eav_attribute_option AS eao',
            "eao.option_id = e.my_attribute",
            array("sort_order" => 'eao.option_id')
        )
        ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('eao.sort_order '.$dir));
}
```