# Load all products from category and filter by selected multi-select attribute in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have two multi-select attributes in my Magento 1.9 install (with their respective options) like this:

**make**

- Manufacturer A
- Manufacturer B
- Manufacturer C

**model**

- Type A
- Type B
- Type C

I have some products that will have more than one "make" and "model".

How do you load all products from a specific category and filter by products having a specific selected multi-select attribute option in Magento?

I am trying to load products where a scenario like this exists:

```
make = [Manufacturer A] and [Manufacturer C]
model = [Type A] and [Type B]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
// Mini-config
$make_attribute_code = 'make';
$model_attribute_code = 'model';
$filter_by_make = 'Manufacturer A';
$filter_by_model = 'Type A';
$load_from_category = 10117;

// Parse attribute option id of "Make"
$make_option_id = null;
$makeAttributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $make_attribute_code);
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($makeAttributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions();
foreach ($attributeOptions as $attributeOption) {
    if (trim($attributeOption['label']) == $filter_by_make) {
        $make_option_id = (int)trim($attributeOption['value']);
        break;
    }
}

// Parse attribute option id of "Model"
$model_option_id = null;
$modelAttributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $model_attribute_code);
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($modelAttributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions();
foreach ($attributeOptions as $attributeOption) {
    if (trim($attributeOption['label']) == $filter_by_model) {
        $model_option_id = (int)trim($attributeOption['value']);
        break;
    }
}

// Load category products having selected "Make" & "Model"
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load($load_from_category)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => $make_attribute_code, 'eq' => $make_option_id)))
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => $model_attribute_code, 'eq' => $model_option_id)))
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );
```

If the product has only one "make" and "model" option selected, it appears to be showing. Any ideas?

Comment: use find in set http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14116/45103

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply multiple value filter, First you need to create an array for all your selected options.

```
$filter_by_make = array('Manufacturer A','Manufacturer B');
```

When you get `IDs` for selected values, create an array for selected values like,

```
foreach ($attributeOptions as $attributeOption) {
    if (in_array(trim($attributeOption['label']), $filter_by_make)) {
        $make_option_id[] = (int)trim($attributeOption['value']);
        break;
    }
}
```

Now in filter section,
Use

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load($load_from_category)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(array('attribute'=>$make_attribute_code, 'finset'=>$make_option_id)))
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );
```

Reference
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14116/23825

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick for me: `->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => $make_attribute_code, 'finset' => array($make_option_id))))` and `->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => $model_attribute_code, 'finset' => array($model_option_id))))`

Comment: I want to show all products section wise, like first option and its products, then 2nd option than its products and so on. So, I have used it within loop function : Like foreach ($optionIds as $optionid):
        $optionid = (int) $optionid; $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->clear()->addAttributeToFilter(
                        array(
                            array('attribute' => "filter_type", 'finset' =>$optionid)
                        )
                    );But its only showing one time with first options products only.