# Magento 2 - How to filter on multiselect product attribute?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

I want to filter multiselect product attribute which has backend type `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend`. So when I save attribute it gets saved as the comma-separated values in the database. So at the time of Product filtering, I applied filter by 2 values as like this

```php
 $this->collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $this->collection->addAttributeToFilter( 'concerns', array('finset' => 'concerns_1,concerns_4'));
```

It's not filtering with the above code (means collection size returning zero) but when I filter on a single value its working fine. Please suggest me how can I filter on multiple values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14116/85907

Comment: I tried that but it's not working for me

Comment: I think one problem with FIND_IN_SET is that it does not check for multiple values at one time. suppose I'm writing SELECT FIND_IN_SET('a,b','a,b,c,d'); its returning 0 however both a & b are in the set , but when I write SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');  its returning 2.

Answer (score 3):

**Need to pass to the addAttributeToFilter and array of arrays.**

```
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
          array('attribute'=>'concerns', 'finset'=>'a'),
          array('attribute'=>'concerns', 'finset'=>'b'),
    )
);
```

**Updated :-**

```
->addAttributeToFilter('concerns', array('in' => $array));
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working. My question was suppose one product has attribute values a,b,c,d and I want to filter on attribute a,d then how can I do that? I tried your as you have provided here but it's not working @rkrathod

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Can we do it in one line? is it possible? because my attribute values are dynamic some time it might have 3 values some time might have 4 value etc. can we handle that type of scenario?

Comment: i think it possible using 'in' condition

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I tried updated one but it's not working